# How to remove crazy characters like 002ÿþÃ¦Ã¦Å“â€°Ã¨Ã¥â€ from text in R?

Tags: r, text-mining, text-processing

Here are the things I did on my corpus -

```
CorpusX = tm_map(CorpusX, content_transformer(tolower))
CorpusX = tm_map(CorpusX, removeWords, c("X", stopwords("english")))
CorpusX = tm_map(CorpusX, removePunctuation)
CorpusX = tm_map(CorpusX, stripWhitespace)
CorpusX = tm_map(CorpusX, removeNumbers)
CorpusX = tm_map(CorpusX, stemDocument)

CorpusX = tm_map(CorpusX, PlainTextDocument)
```

After this I made a Document-Term-Matrix and then word-cloud. 
If I go by this flow and don't make any attempts to remove the characters like those mentioned in the question everything works fine. 
But when I try to remove those characters I get errors like below -

```
>Error in UseMethod("TermDocumentMatrix", x) :    no applicable method
> for 'TermDocumentMatrix' applied to an object of class
> "c('DocumentTermMatrix', 'simple_triplet_matrix')"
```

I am looking for an efficient method to deal with such characters.

PS- I changed the description of question completely because people were getting confused (my fault). 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: The error message seems to be saying something else, namely that your object has the wrong class...

Comment: Actually I tried with both (dtm and tdm) but the error was same. I guess I need to change the question description.

Answer (score 1):

When processing your text, did you use remove any non-english characters?

If you didn't, Here is an example of how to do it. Here we removed numbers, Puncutation and non-English characters.

```
removeNumPunct <- function(x) gsub("[^[:alpha:][:space:]]*","",x)
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(removeNumPunct), lazy = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Frank seems to be on to something, namely that you appear to be using a function intended for an object of class `TermDocumentMatrix` rather than `DocumentTermMatrix`. The `tm` package has functions to transform text corpora into both, called `TermDocumentMatrix` and `DocumentTermMatrix`.

To get at your question, [R is generally not great at handling Unicode](http://www.textasdata.com/2015/02/encoding-headaches-emoticons-and-rs-handling-of-utf-816/). I often move to Python to fix such problems, but the link appears to have some solutions.